# How to subtract and divide the values in bash script and also i would like to know in the form of percent

Tags: bash

I tried this way: `echo $((10000-96756/120))`, but I am facing issues with it. Can anyone please help me how to subtract and divide the values in bash script and also I would like to know in the form of percent

Comment: What do you mean by 'know in the form of percent'?

Comment: @kalyan : You are aware that bash knows only integer arithmetic, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few more brackets :)

```sh
echo $((((10000-96756))/120))
```